Softmax makes inf in nueral network
I am trying to write a simple neural net implementation with Iris dataset. However, when I try to use the softmax as the last activation layer. I got the following error:

RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in subtract   exp_score =
np.exp(X-np.max(X, axis=1,keepdims=True))

Also, if I change the ReLU to cross-entropy, I get a similar error. I checked the dataset and there is no missing data. Can someone help me to identify why I have such an error?
class ReLU():
    def __call__(self, X):
        return np.maximum(0, X)
    
    def derivative(self, X):
        return (X>0).astype(float)

class SoftMax():
    def __call__(self, X):
        exp_score = np.exp(X-np.max(X, axis=1,keepdims=True))
        prob = exp_score/np.sum(exp_score, axis=1, keepdims=True)
        return prob
    

import numpy as np
class MultiLayerNet():
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, output_size, activation_func = ReLU(), loss = "mse", reg_lambda = 0.01, mini_batch =100):
        self.input_size = input_size
        self.output_size = output_size
        self.hidden_sizes = hidden_size
        self.activation = activation_func
        if loss == 'mse':
            self.loss_function = self.cross_entropy_loss
            self.loss_derivative = self.cross_entropy_loss_derivative
        self.minibatch = mini_batch
        self.params = {}
        self.reg_lambda = reg_lambda
        self.layers = [input_size] + hidden_size+[output_size]
        for i in range(1, len(self.layers)):
            self.params[f"W{i}"] = np.random.randn(self.layers[i-1], self.layers[i])/np.sqrt(self.layers[i-1])
            self.params[f"b{i}"] = np.zeros((1, self.layers[i]))
    
    
    def forward(self, X):
        A = X
        self.params["A0"] = X
        for i in range(1, len(self.layers)):
            Z = A @ self.params[f"W{i}"] + self.params[f"b{i}"]
            if i == len(self.layers) - 1:
                A = SoftMax()(Z)
            else:
                A = self.activation(Z)
            self.params[f"Z{i}"] = Z
            self.params[f"A{i}"] = A
        return A
    
    def backward(self, X, y):
        y = y.reshape(-1, 1) if len(y.shape) == 1 else y
        output = self.params[f"A{len(self.layers)-1}"]
        d = self.loss_derivative(output, y)
        for i in reversed(range(1, len(self.layers))):
            self.params[f"dw{i}"] = self.params[f"A{i-1}"].T @ d + self.reg_lambda * self.params[f"W{i}"]
            self.params[f"db{i}"] = np.sum(d, axis=0, keepdims = True)
            if i > 1:
                d = d @ self.params[f"W{i}"].T * self.activation.derivative(self.params[f"Z{i-1}"])
                
    
    def train(self, X, y, num_epochs=500, learning_rate=0.01):
        for i in range(num_epochs):
            self.forward(X)
            self.backward(X,y)
            for i in range(1, len(self.layers)):
                self.params[f"W{i}"] -= learning_rate * self.params[f"dw{i}"]
                self.params[f"b{i}"] -= learning_rate * self.params[f"db{i}"]
            loss = self.loss_function(self.params[f"A{len(self.layers)-1}"], y.reshape(-1, 1))
            if i%100 == 0:
                print("loss {}".format(loss))

Update: I found that with a smaller epoch, it works with very poor accuracy. However if I increase the epoch, the input of the SoftMax in the forward function will start to have inf, which causes the error.
def forward(self, X):
        A = X
        self.params["A0"] = X
        for i in range(1, len(self.layers)):
            
            Z = A @ self.params[f"W{i}"] + self.params[f"b{i}"]
            if i == len(self.layers)-1:
              #problem here when having larger epoch number  
            A = SoftMax()(Z) 


Can you show what X is when the warning occured? Maybe adding try: ... except: print(X) on that line of code
